# Php regex replace elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

im trying to change html elements inside PHP.

first is to replace textarea with h1.
Thing needs to be replaced looks something like this:

```
<textarea class="head" id="hd_x">Random headline</textarea>
```

Im trying to change to this:

```
<h1 class="head" id="hd_x">Random headline</h1>
```

**Random headline** can be- Dog like cats, Cats dont like dogs.

**X** in id can be number- hd_1, hd_2 and so on( but i think it is no needed to be touched, so it can be ignored ).

Second is need to replace textarea with p. Original looks something like this:

```
<textarea class="text" id="txt_x">Random text</textarea>
```

Im trying to change to this:

```
<p class="text" id="txt_x">Random text</h1>
```

Random text and X here works same as on first one

If you can figure out what im trying to do and it is possible and short then tt would be nice if you help me to do only the H1 part. I think i can figure `<p>` (2nd) part out it.

I tryed to do it with str_replace but the problem is that then it is always replacing `</textarea>` with `</h1>` or with `</p>`

Thank you

---

My idea is is that i need 2 separate preg_replace. One of them recognizes this part:

```
<textarea class="head"
```

knows it needs to replace with :

```
<h1 class="head"
```

Thems skips over this part:

```
id="hd_x">Random headline
```

then it preg_replace recognizes again this one:

```
</textarea>
```

and replaces with:

```
</h1>
```

Trying to make it short. Finds by this(???? is part that should be ignored and left untouched):

```
<textarea class="head" ??????????????????</textarea>
```

and replaced with(????? is part that was untouched):

class="head" i think is needed cause preg_replace pattern figures out this way that it need to replace with h1 not with p.

Comment: Have you considered using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this? Would save you a lot of regex headache.

Comment: Everyone will say dont use regex for parsing structured text. Unless you plan for nested constructs you'll be in for a surprise and a few bug reports. Use a parser unless you are good with regex

Comment: The DOMDocument is the way i should it do, but because it is totally new for me i figured other way that i worked for me. I still went with str_replace. I just droped <h1> and now everything is replaced with <p> and that way code done need to figure out if it is H1 or P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use RegEx to change HTML elements. The DOM recognizes the structure and xpath makes it easy to do what you want:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea class="head" id="hd_x">Random headline</textarea>
    <textarea class="text" id="hd_x">Random headline</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$names = array(
  'head' => 'h1', 'text' => 'p'
);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//textarea[@class="head" or @class="text"]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  // create the new node depending on the class attribute
  $type = $node->getAttribute('class');
  $newNode = $dom->createElement($names[$type]);
  // fetch all attributes of the current node
  $attributes = $xpath->evaluate('@*', $node);
  // and append them to the new node
  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $newNode->appendChild($attribute);
  }
  // replace the current node with the new node
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
}

var_dump($dom->saveHtml());
```